# Clickable table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, clickable

I created a simple function in JS that generates a table. Now I want to do this: when I click on some cell of the table, the page will **alert the value what is inside the cell: variable b**, as you can see in the code. I tried it, but I didn´t managed it. is inside the code. I also used Jquery.

The code: **JS**

```
    function gen() {
        var rowData = '';
        for (var a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
            rowData += '<tr>';
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                
                rowData += '<td>';

                rowData += b;

                rowData += '</td>';

                b++;

            }
            rowData += "</tr>";
            
        }

        $('#myTableId2').append(rowData);


    }
```

**HTML:**

```
 <table id="myTableId2"> </table>
 <button onclick="gen()">Generate</button>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
rowData += '<td onclick="alert(this.innerHTML)">';
```

Comment: @DavidKristek: If Steve's answer solved your problem, please be sure to mark it as the accepted answer. You may also consider upvoting it.

Answer (score -1):

I see you're using jQuery.  You can attach a `click()` event to each `<td>` element as I do below.

Note that since `b` is undefined in your example, I took the liberty of giving it a random value for illustrative purposes.

```js
function gen() {
  let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1; //generate random value
  var rowData = '';
  for (var a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
    rowData += '<tr>';
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

      rowData += '<td>';

      rowData += b;

      rowData += '</td>';

      b++;

    }
    rowData += "</tr>";

  }

  $('#myTableId2').append(rowData);

  //attach the click event using jQuery
  $("td").click(function(){alert(this.innerText)});

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTableId2"> </table>
<button onclick="gen()">Generate</button>
```